# HTML Select Element bound to Observable, but options are blank even after observable returns

Tags: angular

I have a select selement that is bound to an Observable data source. In my initialize of my component, I am subscribing to the observable, so that when it returns I modify the options.

However, it seems there's a slight delay between the observable returning data and binding that data to the HTML element. How do I account for this delay, without using a setTimeout.

```
this.aggregateGroups.subscribe(data => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(this.aggregateControl.options.length);
      }, 0);
});
```

If I don't have the settimeout, the Select input has a length of 0;

Comment: Can you show your select statement?

Comment: Do you mean that the Observable doesn't give you data anymore when you subscribe? In that case you might want to look into a `ReplaySubject`. The `ReplaySubject` keeps a buffer so that all subscribers will receive the last N broadcasted values. See also: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md

Comment: It gives me the data. I am currently using a ReplaySubject. What I mean is that when the Observable returns, the data isn't yet bound to the HTML Select control, and I'm trying to figure out a cleaner way to wait for that binding to happen instead of using setTimeout of 0 seconds to create an artificial delay.